# Apache Camel: Send Text Message with Twilio

Tags: java, apache-camel, twilio

I'm trying to send a text message over Apache Camel using the [`camel-twilio` component](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-twilio/src/main/docs/twilio-component.adoc). Since I never used the Twilio API (neither natively nor using Apache Camel), I'm not sure if I got the parameters right. Here's the method I wrote:

```
/**
 * Sends a text message to the given recipient's number (parameter to)
 * 
 * @param username:
 *            Twilio username (email)
 * @param password:
 *            Twilio password (in plain text)
 * @param accountSid:
 *            Twilio account sid (from the dashboard)
 * @param from:
 *            registered phone number (starting with country prefix +XX)
 * @param to:
 *            the recipient's phone number (starting with country prefix +XX)
 * @param message:
 *            the message to be sent (plain text)
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static void sendTextMessage(String username, String password, String accountSid, String from, String to,
        String message) throws Exception {
    String route = String.format("twilio:message/creator?username=%s&password=%s&accountSid=%s&from=%s&to=%s",
            username, password, accountSid, from, to);
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("direct:message").to(route);
        }
    });
    context.start();
    ProducerTemplate producer = context.createProducerTemplate();
    producer.sendBody("direct:message", message);
    context.stop();
}
```

The most important line is the creation of the route, the first of the method. When I'm running this method with parameters according to the JavaDoc, I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: Missing properties for creator, need one or more from [pathAccountSid, mediaUrl, messagingServiceSid, body]
```

So I thought to add the parameter `messagingServiceSid`, providing my `accountSid` again:

```
String route = String.format("twilio:message/creator?username=%s&password=%s&accountSid=%s&from=%s&to=%s&messagingServiceSid=%s",
            username, password, accountSid, from, to, accountSid);
```

Now I get this error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method for message/creator, with arguments [messagingServiceSid, from, to]
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: These are my Maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-twilio</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

EDIT 2: Here's the modified and working version of the method:

```
/**
 * Sends a text message to the given recipient's number (parameter to)
 * 
 * @param accountSid:
 *            Twilio account sid (from the dashboard)
 * @param authToken:
 *            Twilio auth token (from the dashboard)
 * @param from:
 *            registered phone number (starting with country prefix +XX)
 * @param to:
 *            the recipient's phone number (starting with country prefix +XX)
 * @param message:
 *            the message to be sent (plain text)
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static void sendTextMessage(String accountSid, String authToken, String from, String to, String message)
        throws Exception {
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    TwilioComponent twilio = context.getComponent("twilio", TwilioComponent.class);
    twilio.getConfiguration().setUsername(accountSid);
    twilio.getConfiguration().setPassword(authToken);
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("direct:message")
                    .setHeader("CamelTwilioTo", constant(new PhoneNumber(to)))
                    .setHeader("CamelTwilioFrom", constant(new PhoneNumber(from)))
                    .setHeader("CamelTwilioBody", constant(message))
                    .to("twilio://message/creator");

        }
    });
    context.start();
    ProducerTemplate producer = context.createProducerTemplate();
    producer.sendBody("direct:message", message);
    context.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to say that to work efficiently with camel-twilio, you need to have a good understanding on [Twilio Java API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-java/index.html). In your case, let's get familiar with the `MessageCreator` API here:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-java/7.17.0/com/twilio/rest/api/v2010/account/MessageCreator.html

With that said, first of all, since the `username` (i.e. `accountSid`) and `password` should be something shared in a camel-twilio component, let's set them at the component:

```
TwilioComponent twilio = context.getComponent("twilio", TwilioComponent.class);
twilio.getConfiguration().setUsername(username);
twilio.getConfiguration().setPassword(password);
```

(Note most of the time the twilio username and accoundSid refer to the same thing, so you can use only one of them.)

Once the username/password are set up, let's use the `MessageCreator`. The simplest constructor you can use would be `MessageCreator(PhoneNumber to, PhoneNumber from, String body)`, but since `to` and `from` have to be `PhoneNumber` instances, it's easier to pass them to the endpoint as Camel message headers instead of embedding them to the endpoint URI as endpoint parameters. (NOTE: Any of the camel-twilio endpoint options can be provided in a message header with `CamelTwilio` prefix.)

This would look something like the following:

```
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:message")
            .setHeader("CamelTwilioTo", constant(new PhoneNumber(to)))
            .setHeader("CamelTwilioFrom", constant(new PhoneNumber(from)))
            .setHeader("CamelTwilioBody", constant(message))
            .to("twilio://message/creator");
    }
```

Note, at this moment, the endpoint URI can be as simple as `twilio://message/creator`.

Now you should be able to send texts to Twilio.

FYI, there is a working example of camel-twilio with Spring Boot:
https://github.com/tadayosi/demo-camel-hawtio-springboot

Comment: When I use the account sid instead of the user name and the auth token instead of the password, it works! Thank you so much!